# Does the A001921 linear recurrent integer sequence always yield composite numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, divisibility

Let $(a_n)$ be the [A001921](http://oeis.org/A001921) sequence

$$
  a_0 := 0,\ a_1 := 7, \quad a_{n+2} = 14a_{n+1} - a_n + 6.
$$

Is it true that $a_n$ is always a composite integer for any $n\geq 2$ ?

UPDATE : I now make a much stronger conjecture : if we define $b_k$ as the gcd of all the integers $a_{2^kn+2^{k-1}-1}(n\geq 0)$, then $(b_k)_{k\geq 1}$ is increasing (numerical values suggest it grows very very fast, see below). For example :

- $a_{2n}$ is always divisible by $b_0=2$.
- $a_{4n+1}$ is always divisible by $b_1=7$.
- $a_{8n+3}$ is always divisible by $b_2=97$.
- $a_{16n+7}$ is always divisible by $b_3=607$.
- $a_{32n+15}$ is always divisible by $b_4=708158977$.
- $a_{64n+31}$ is always divisible by $b_5=1002978273411373057$.
- $a_{128n+63}$ is always divisible by $b_6=2011930833870518011412817828051050497$.

Comment: By simple computations (i.e. looking at the sequence mod 2, 7, and 15), we can prove that the only positions where $a$ might be prime are $a_{12n+7}$ (otherwise, one of $2$, $7$, or $15$ divides it)

Comment: Yeah; you're right. $a_{12n+11}$ is still a suspicious case too.

Comment: Why you considered $a(64n+17)$ and not $a(64n+33)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered completely on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186390/tower-of-squares-sequence-divides-linear-recurrent-a001921-sequence).

To summarize, the conjecture is true because if we put $\alpha=2-\sqrt{3}$ and
$\beta=2+\sqrt{3}$, then $a_n=u_nv_{n+1}$ where $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$
are the integer sequences defined by

$$
u_n=\frac{\beta^n-\alpha^n}{\beta-\alpha}, \
v_n=\frac{\alpha^{n}+\beta^{n}}{2}
$$

and $b_n=v_{2^n}$.